# For what values of $p$ does this series converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, education

This is a question we asked on a second semester calculus test.

For what values of $p$ does this series converge?
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(1/n)}{n^p}$$

I believe that it actually can be shown that $p> 0$ is a valid answer.

However. I am interested in finding a proof that is simple enough that a beginning calculus student could do on their own cognition.
Is there a simple way to give the exact values of $p$ for which the series converges?

Comment: **Hint:** $\sin x\simeq x$ when $x\simeq0$.

Comment: we can showe convergency for p>0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Limit comparison test.

$$\lim \frac{\sin(1/n)/n^p}{1/n^{p+1}}=1,$$

$\sum\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}$ converges when $p>0$, diverges when $p\leq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
\sin \frac1n \approx \frac1n,
$$
your series is equivalent to
$$
\sum_n \frac{1}{n^{p+1}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\sin 1/n}{n^p} \sim \frac{1/n}{n^{p}} \,\,\, \text{if }n\to \infty
$$
so I guess every $p>0$ :)

Answer (score 1):

Comparison test:

1. Note that $$-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1 ~~ \forall ~x$$
2. Therefore, $$\dfrac{\sin(x)}{f(n)} \leq \dfrac{1}{f(n)} ~~ \forall ~x$$

So for your case: $f(n)=n^p$. This converges by $p$-series when $p>1$. Therefore, your original series converges for the same.

You cannot use alternating series test, since:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \rightarrow 0^+$$
Thus, the series ends up being strictly positive for large enough $n$.

Comment: Yes, this was the answer we were looking for, but now I am realizing that a more robust answer can be given.